# ssconvert merges column in output

Tags: unix, ssconvert

I have problems with the ssconvert. The input is a tab-separated tsv-file that should be converted to xls (not xlsx), but the output combines some on the columns into one long string. Any ideas?

Comment: post the minimum amount of data that demostrates this problem and the exact options you are using when you run `ssconvert`. Good luck.